# Does something that is injective, surjective or bijective imply that it is a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

As the title says.

Sorry it seems like a silly question but it's something I've been wondering because it seems like sometimes the word "function" is omitted, but other times it is included

Comment: Example?${}{}{}$

Comment: A partial injection is not (always) a function, but I suppose that's more of an example of the [red herring principle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle).

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, I know exactly what you are talking about and it can be incredibly confusing, because mathematics literature is that way.

The general answer is no; simply stating that a binary relation $R:X \mapsto Y$ is injective or surjective alone does not imply it is a function (note that bijection implies function, but function does not imply bijection).

Here is a useful set of definitions, which always hold true:

[image]

Now, why are you confused? Because some literature uses the terms **inj**, **surj**, and **bij** in particular to refer to *functions*. Here is an example from the same online notes:

[image]

Yes, this is confusing and a bad habit. But it is common in literature. The short answer is read carefully any definitions the author makes.